# How to progamatically create pages in gatsby with a CMS backend?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a Django CMS that serves as my back-end application. And I'm trying to create pages dynamically in my Gatsby front-end site. My Django application is exposed over GraphQL using Graphene. But I'm not able to query the slugs from backend CMS and create pages using `gatsby-node.js`. How do I create pages when I create a page in the back-end application?

The idea being

```
//gatsby-node.js

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const pages = graphql`
        {
            blogPages{
                edges{
                    node{
                        slug     // this slug supposed to come from the backend CMS (Atleast i think)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `;

    const { createPage } = actions
    const blogTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blogTemplate.js`);

    pages.blogPages.edges.forEach(edge => {   //this should help to create dynamic pages - slug coming from backend CMS
      const slug = edge.node.blogpage.slug;
      createPage({
        path: slug,
        component: blogTemplate
    })  
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you make that query for `blogPages` in graphiql?

Comment: From back-end I can make that query using graphiql.. and from the frontend I can use apollo to make that query dynamically in components. I have decided not to use gatsby-source-wagtail as it does not give me dynamic query (Does not update if i create new node in the backend CMS unless rebiuld the application for build - refetch interval only works for dev env)

Comment: `createPage` can be used only within build/dev - deployed site can be uploaded to static server then **no dynamic page cration** possibility - only dynamic data loading/js/react/apollo [client-side] logic - use webhook to build(redeploy) entire site

Comment: Agree with @xadm. You might have some luck using `gatsby-source-graphql` first so that this `createPages` step is possible. When you create a new page in Django CMS,  trigger a webhook with your host to rebuild the project, sourcing the newly created content.

Comment: Thanks @xadm then in that case is there a possibility to do the apollo client side logic to fetch slug in some component and import the result to the gatsby-node.js.. or this idea totally against the lifecycle of gatsby-node.js

Comment: static server means only serving files, no nodejs server, it can be apache/nginx/whatever even without php etc. - it has to be rerun on nodejs env ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's been said in the comments already, but just to summarize: since Gatsby is a static site generator you cannot dynamically add pages at runtime. Each page corresponds to its own html file that needs to be created on your webserver. That is not something you can do at runtime.

What you can do is to set up a continuous integration workflow where you have a build running in the cloud somewhere. Trigger it when you make a change in Django, or alternatively run it regularly (hourly/daily) to update the site.

If running a rebuild does not work for your use case you need to look at an entirely different architecture.